# How do I pass DataGridView selected row value to TextBox in another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-4.5

I am using Windows Forms on .NET 4.5.2. I have 2 Forms. Form1 has a DataGridView that contains field from database and a button that shows Form2 when clicked. Form2 has a TextBox. I want to fill it with text from one of Form1 DataGridView fields when I click a button in Form1. Is it possible? The Form2 Textbox modifier is set to public but it is still not working.

I have tried:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Form2 fr = new Form2();
    int row = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
    fr.Textbox1.Text = Convert.ToString(DataGridView1[0, row].Value);
    fr.Textbox2.Text = Convert.ToString(DataGridView1[1, row].Value);    
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 fr = new Form2();
    fr.ShowDialog();  
}
```

Comment: remove Form2 fr=new Form2(); from button1_Click and CellContentClick method and paste it outside of both methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem exists because you are using `ShowDialog()` method instead of `Show()`. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20859112/10303335) on Stack Overflow:

> The Show function shows the form in a non modal form. This means that you can click on the parent form.
>
> ShowDialog shows the form modally, meaning you cannot go to the parent form.

Somehow that interacts with passing the value from one form to another, I think it happens because the first form gets blocked (paused) after `ShowDialog()` method therefore preventing you from copying the value from DataGridView.

If you used `ShowDialog()` method on purpose, then you can try to bypass this limitation somehow. For example, I managed to pass the required value from DataGridView to TextBox in a newly created Form (lets call it Form2) by using the *Owner* property (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7013420/10303335) too) and *Form.Shown* event. You can try replacing your code with this piece in your *button1_Click* event handler (or probably just creating Shown event handler in your file with Form2 class):

```cs
Form2 fr = new Form2();
int row = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
fr.Shown += (senderfr, efr) => 
{
    // I did null check because I used the same form as Form2 :) 
    // You can probably omit this check.
    if (fr.Owner == null) return;

    var ownerForm = (Form1)fr.Owner;
    fr.Textbox1.Text = ownerForm.DataGridView1[0, row].Value.ToString();
    fr.Textbox2.Text = ownerForm.DataGridView1[1, row].Value.ToString();
};
fr.ShowDialog(this);
```

**P.S.** Why would you use `Convert.ToString()` instead of simply calling `ToString()` method on Value property like I did in the example?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203389/discussion-on-answer-by-ymdred16-how-do-i-pass-datagridview-selected-row-value-t).

Answer (score 0):

First you should do the Form1's datagridview modifiers public.
When you click the button from Form1, open the Form2 and write this code to Form2_Load().

```
 Form1 frm = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
 int row = frm.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
 Textbox1.Text = Convert.ToString(frm.DataGridView1[0, row].Value);
 Textbox2.Text = Convert.ToString(frm.DataGridView1[1, row].Value);
```

This should work.

Comment: However this breaks encapsulation. Probably author doesn't care about it in this case, but still it is be better to be warned.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the warning. But like you said, the author probably does not care.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Form2 fr = new Form2();
  private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int row = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
    fr.Textbox1.Text = Convert.ToString(DataGridView1[0, row].Value);
    fr.Textbox2.Text = Convert.ToString(DataGridView1[1, row].Value);    
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fr.ShowDialog();  
}
```

Comment: This will never work. How did you read other answers before posting yours one?

Comment: according to your code, you make objects 2 times every time you make a new object in first part you assigned values to object then next you also make a new object which is not getting the values.

Comment: the new instance of object will never get your values.

Comment: First of all, that's not my code neither am I the one who asked the question. I misunderstood your code at first, probably this would work. But there are a few cons: you break encapsulation and what if it is needed to create a new form every time the button is clicked?